# How can I make instances of a class into a list using a json file

Tags: java, json, list

I'm currently creating a Cluedo game and I'm editing the `playerpiece` class, I have also created a json file called `data.json` to store data about the playerpiece, for instance: Character Names(e.g Colonel Mustard), Weapon etc.
I have the following json which I need to convert into list of java objects

```
{
  "PlayerPieces": {
    "0": "Col Mustard",
    "1": "Prof Plum",
    "2": "Rev Green",
    "3": "Mrs Peacock",
    "4": "Miss Scarlett",
    "5": "Mrs White"
  }
}
```

At the moment I have a PlayerPiece class and I'm trying to use the string from the `data.json` to make an instance of PlayerPiece and then add it to the list, something like `List<PlayerPieces>`,  any help or tips on how to get started on the playerpiece class would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's some tutorials about handling json with java https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper of ‘jackson-databind’ library. Below is the sample for converting json file to java objectz

> List list = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), PlayerPiecea[].class));

Ref [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

p.s your data.json file need to be changed to start with json array instead of json object.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `HashMap<String, String>` with this json :

```
{
    "0": "Col Mustard",
    "1": "Prof Plum",
    "2": "Rev Green",
    "3": "Mrs Peacock",
    "4": "Miss Scarlett",
    "5": "Mrs White"
  }
```